# Newsletter open and click tracking use http. Can i configure it that it uses https with our certificate? Can this cause block bounces?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ssl, certificates

We recently saw that a particular domain (lets say it is recipient.com operated by recipient ltd) of newsletter recipients block our newsletter quite often. Therefore we asked the operating company of that domain what is wrong with our newsletters.

Recipient LTD told us:

> - Use [clean urls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL) and that this is the reason why
>     our newsletter are regarded as spam or virus and get blocked.
> - Only refer to valid, trusted URLs in your e-mails and make sure that
>     there is no risk of confusion. Don't link to a phishing site and don't
>     quote or forward links to malware or spam. Also not as an example or
>     for fun!
> - For security reasons, our servers do not allow **unencrypted**
>     **transfer of executable formats** such as those used by viruses, worms
>     and Trojans.
>
>   - Examples: ade, adp, app, **asp**, bas, bat, bhx, cab, ceo,
>       chm, cmd, com, cpl, crt, csr, der, exe, fxp, hlp, hta, iframe, inf,
>       ins, isp, its, js, jse, lnk, mad, maf, mag, mam, mar, mas, matte, mde,
>       mim, msc, msi, msp, mst, ole, pcd, pif, reg, scr, sct, shb, shs, vb,
>       vbe, vbmacros, vbs, vsw, wmd, ws, wsc, wsf, wsh and xxe.Because spam or virus sender often use links with ids to cover the real target of that url.

Furthermore we saw that we created every link in our newsletter with https but it gets wrapped like:

`http://click.ourdomain.com/?qs=65a074a335071185581e968250a74788b72109cb3c4eec81f11a111eac1696522ec229b01733cb96b9ede10b706c1ae6a688533974ef5952`

(we selfhost the dns entries and do not use a subdomain or different domain to send our emails)

The open tracking looks like this:

`http://click.ourdomain.com/open.aspx?ffcb10-fec41577776c0078-fe5f1077716c047d7713-fe4615111564047e701470-ff5f17757d-fe5a11727c61027d7217-ffce15`

Questions:

- How can we configure salesforce to wrap these links in https?
- Has anybody else experienced problems that the tracking functionality (opens,clicks,...) of newsletters causes block bounces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best practice to keep all content referenced from emails, linked using https - as it indeed can impact your sender reputation, I have seen this myself in more than few cases.

You need to purchase two SSL certificates from Salesforce. One will be used for securing image URLs and the second will be used for links, Cloud Pages, and other resources on your SAP domain. You can choose to provide Salesforce with SSL certificates of your own choice, or let them purchase the certificates on your behalf. Regardless what you choose, the price will be the same - most of the cost is related to handling and installing them.
Once implemented, you will be able to use https URLs in your emails.

Find additional information on the [help page.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232477&type=1)